# How to solve ToDate issue in DatePicker Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery DatePicker in my code but I am facing some annoying issue and that is when I clicked on ToDate it is minimum than startDate. I'm new to jQuery and don't know how to solve this issue. Please look a code which I try.

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
                from = $("#StartDate")
                    .datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 1
                    })
                    .on("change", function () {
                        to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
                    }),
                to = $("#EndDate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1
                })
                    .on("change", function () {
                        from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
                    });

            function getDate(element) {
                var date;
                try {
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
                } catch (error) {
                    date = null;
                }
                return date;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: "when I clicked on ToDate it is minimum than startDate" - do you mean the issue is that the ToDate, is lower than startData ?

Comment: Yes@RomiHalasz correct

Answer (score 0):

You can set the min date for your Datepicker (ToDate)

`var start_date = $("#StartDate").val();`

```
to = $("#EndDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1
})
```

Change it to

```
to = $("#EndDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: start_date,
    numberOfMonths: 1
})
```

Comment: No it shouldn’t work in my case because in toDate it always pick a value of current date but let suppose my start date is 01 jan 2020 and i want that my todate is not lower than 01 jan 2020

Comment: you can set the start date as a minDate for end datepicker